# How to set NativeScript as RTL Layout by default

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm building an Arabic app so it's RTL language I have tried to install that package `@nativescript-rtl/ui`.

But nothing really happens to the layout! still the same as LTR

> ( I tried the plugin on tabs sample from NativeScript angular )

Then I had registered elements for RTL on `app.module.ts` like what shows on docs:

```
import * as rtl from '@nativescript-rtl/ui'

registerElement(
    "RGridLayout",
    () => rtl.GridLayout
);
registerElement(
    "RWrapLayout",
    () => rtl.WrapLayout
);
registerElement(
    "RAbsoluteLayout",
    () => rtl.AbsoluteLayout
);
registerElement(
    "RDockLayout",
    () => rtl.DockLayout
);
registerElement(
    "RStackLayout",
    () => rtl.StackLayout
);
```

Then I have used the elements `RStackLayout` on `app.component.html`

```xml
<RStackLayout>
    <Tabs selectedIndex="0" tabsPosition="bottom">
        <TabStrip>
            <!--
                Besides the approach demonstrated below there is alternative shorthand syntax for setting TabStripItem title and icon:

                <TabStripItem title="Home" iconSource="res://tabIcons/home" />

                Both shorthand and verbose syntax can use
                TabStripItem Label {...} css selector to style the title label,
                and TabStriptItem Image {...} css selector to style the icon image (see _app-common.scss).
                Note that when working with font icons we recommend the usage of the verbose syntax as it
                is explicit and describes better the need to provide font icon as well as set the respective font (e.g. via class name).
             -->
            <TabStripItem>
                <!--
                    Note TabStripItem will only accept single Label and/or single Image elements that it
                    will "adopt"; any other layout elements you try to specify will be ignored
                -->
                <Label text="Home"></Label>
                <Image src="font://&#xf015;" class="fa t-36"></Image>
            </TabStripItem>
            <TabStripItem>
                <Label text="Browse"></Label>
                <Image src="font://&#xf1ea;" class="fa t-36"></Image>
            </TabStripItem>
            <TabStripItem>
                <Label text="Search"></Label>
                <Image src="font://&#xf002;" class="fa t-36"></Image>
            </TabStripItem>
        </TabStrip>

        <TabContentItem>
            <page-router-outlet name="homeTab"></page-router-outlet>
        </TabContentItem>

        <TabContentItem>
            <page-router-outlet name="browseTab"></page-router-outlet>
        </TabContentItem>

        <TabContentItem>
            <page-router-outlet name="searchTab"></page-router-outlet>
        </TabContentItem>
    </Tabs>

</RStackLayout>
```

## Update:

**I tried some text on arabic and it's redirected to RTL But The Tabs is not RTL! how to force it as RTL element**

Comment: RTL can be handled in various different ways, even without the plugin. For example, you may switch your column alignment in Flexbox, set layout directions natively on TabView etc., For Labels / TextFields, they turn into RTL by default when the language you use reads RTL. So please be more specific about which component you are trying to build at the moment and what specific issue you are facing. Also you could show some examples / screenshots of what you are expecting vs what you have now.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'm using the `Tabs` `TabStrip` component to build a tabs view How to turn it to RTL?  So the animation and the order of tabs be from RTL

Answer (score 0):

In `loaded` event of `TabView` you may set the layout direction to `RTL`.

```
onTabViewLoaded(event) {
    if (event.object.android) {
        event.object.android.setLayoutDirection(android.util.LayoutDirection.RTL);
    }
}
```

Use declare statement if you haven't installed `tns-platform-declarations`.

```
declare var android;
```

Comment: Didn't work either with the `Tabs` Component or `TabView` component! 
 adding `(loaded)="onTabViewLoaded($event)"` didn't do anything still the layout LTR! if you could share some working samples I will be appreciated

Comment: As I said I'm not sure what is in your mind, you may probably add a screenshot. But this code turns the layout direction for sure. Swipe between tabs too work in opposite direction.

Comment: Just using the app as RTL by default that what in mind!!!!!! the code not working with me I don't know why till now, Anyway thanks for the help, NS for sure is useless I troubleshooting more than I work with it. 

I have finished the app with Flutter in the end and make the app as RTL is one line code nothing mysterious like NS

Answer (score 0):

The use of `@nativescript-rtl/ui` only affect the elements that you register (`RGridLayout` etc .. )

In order to make the entire app RTL you should use:

```
# app.module.ts

import {
  android as Android,
  AndroidActivityEventData,
  AndroidApplication } from '@nativescript/core/application';

Android.addEventListener(AndroidApplication.activityCreatedEvent, (event: AndroidActivityEventData) => {
  event.activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(android.view .View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
});
```

This will make (i.e) the ActionBar align to the right ( on android ) vs to the left...

Maybe it will affect tabs as well ...